# jhipster: npm complains about node.js version

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, jhipster

I'm using node.js 4.2.2 on windows. After creating my project structure I got this warn:

npm WARN engine karma@0.12.35: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"4.2.2","npm":"2.14.7"})
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.5
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.5

is it possible to make this work with 4.2.2 version?

Comment: the package maintainer would have to update their package to fix/change their dependency info in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning, you can ignore it.

JHipster needs to update Karma but it's not as easy as expected.